# How to place a textView inside a textView in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, textview

So, I have a text view(A message), inside which I want to display the time, in the bottom right corner, while ensuring that the text content in the message does not overlay on it and wraps around. Now, I can manage the program part of how to get the time and set text and all, but what I am not able to do is to place the date inside the text view, something like this:

Here is what I have managed to do:

[image]

And here is what I want:

[image]

Could anyone please tell how can I place a text view like this inside another text View.

Thank You!

Comment: Have your tried cardview?

Comment: Could you please explain it in an anwer as, I am just a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to archive this.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/green_2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/time"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_done_all_24" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And output be like this:-

[image]

**Hope you helpful!**

Comment: Glad to help you. Happy coding!